# Video View Customize agora.io

Tags: flutter, agora.io

How can I customize the calling view in a flutter of agora SDK?
I want to customize the AgoraRenderWidget.
ex- If someone disables the video so I want to show dummy image instead of video.

Answer (score 0):

`AgoraRendererWidget` can be customized as per your use case. For this particular use case whenever a video is turned off during a call i.e. `disableVideo()` is called it triggers the [onUserEnableVideo(false)](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/java/v2.8.0/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1_i_rtc_engine_event_handler.html#af87247218ec1ef398a9478672ad4dd49) callback.

You can use this callback function to trigger your dummy image instead of the video.

I hope this answer your query.